# Terraform - Statuscode=404 (ResourceNotFound)

Tags: azure, terraform

I've been using Terraform for a few weeks and it's a great tool.

However, as of late, I've been getting numerous errors during deployment.

I have a basic Azure deployment .tf file which creates all of the required components. But, for some reason, i keep getting ResourceNotFound. If i re-run the script it works fine.

The main culprit is the "azurerm_virtual_network" resource. Any resources that are dependencies of that seem to fail because the Virtual Network is still "Creating.." when it tries to add NSG rules or "azurerm_subnet".

It's not a show stopper, it's more of an annoyance! Is there a way to prevent this error?

On a side not: I also seem to have to deploy the NSG rules after everything has applied otherwise the NSG rules seem to have no affect. I currently have 2 x .tf files in different folders which i run in order, and the NSG rules work fine doing it this way. Although, i'd prefer it all in one file if possible?

```
// Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "Prod_VirtualNetwork" {
  name          = "virtual-network"
  address_space = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
  location      = "${var.azurerm_location}"

  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
}

// Subnet configurtion
resource "azurerm_subnet" "Prod_subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "virtual-network"
  address_prefix       = "10.1.12.0/24"
}

// Network Security group for Web Servers
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "Prod_nsg_Webservers" {
  name     = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-web-01"
  location = "${var.azurerm_location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
}

// Network Security group for DB Servers
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "Prod_nsg_DBservers" {
  name     = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-db-01"
  location = "${var.azurerm_location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
}

// Network Security group rule for RDP inbound to Web01
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "Prod_nsgrule_RDP_Web01" {
  name                        = "Web-RDP-IN"
  priority                    = 200
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "3389"
  destination_port_range      = "3389"
  source_address_prefix       = ""
  destination_address_prefix  = "10.1.12.5"
  resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
  network_security_group_name = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-web-01"
}

// Network Security group rule for web/80 inbound to Web01
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "Prod_nsgrule_http_Web01" {
  name                        = "Web-HTTP-IN"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "80"
  destination_port_range      = "80"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "10.1.12.5"
  resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
  network_security_group_name = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-web-01"
}

// Network Security group rule for Octopus Deploy inbound to Web01
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "Prod_nsgrule_octopus_Web01" {
  name                        = "Web-Octo-IN"
  priority                    = 110
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "10933"
  destination_port_range      = "10933"
  source_address_prefix       = ""
  destination_address_prefix  = "10.1.12.5"
  resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
  network_security_group_name = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-web-01"
}

// Network Security group rule for Octopus Deploy inbound to DB01
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "Prod_nsgrule_octopus_DB01" {
  name                        = "DB-Octo-IN"
  priority                    = 120
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "10933"
  destination_port_range      = "10933"
  source_address_prefix       = ""
  destination_address_prefix  = "10.1.12.4"
  resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
  network_security_group_name = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-db-01"
}

// Network Security group rule for RDP inbound to DB01
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "Prod_nsgrule_RDP_DB01" {
  name                        = "DB-RDP-IN"
  priority                    = 220
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "3389"
  destination_port_range      = "3389"
  source_address_prefix       = ""
  destination_address_prefix  = "10.1.12.4"
  resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
  network_security_group_name = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-db-01"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any explicit dependency between your virtual network and the subnet, you've hardcoded the network name so I don't think Terraform will create a dependency.

If you change your subnet definition to:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "Prod_subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.azurerm_prefix}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.Prod_RG.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.Prod_VirtualNetwork.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.1.12.0/24"
}
```

That should give Terraform the clue that one needs to be created before the other.

Comment: @boggit excellent good spot! not sure why i hardcoded it like that. I've been using a variable prefix on my nsg rules e.g ${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-web-01 - i've now changed it to resource name.name on the rules and it seems to be running through ok. Lets see if this fixes the NSG rules not working issue mentioned above. Thanks again!!

Comment: Deployed OK, except NSG rules dont work. Removing the NSG's and re-creating resolves the issue though. Possibly a bug?

Comment: I can't see how the NSG's are referenced, generally using Terraform's `${terraform_resource.name.*}` syntax is how it works out dependencies so I would expect you'd refer to the NSG name or ID when creating dependent resources. I've not done anything with Azure and Terraform just mostly AWS so I don't know if this is normal behaviour with NSG's.

Comment: apologies for misspelling your username! I'm doing it that way now, seems to run find and create everything that i have specified. However, the rules dont seem to work. I have to delete and re-create them.

Comment: Actually yes I see now, it's the same problem. You're referring to the NSG in rules with `${var.azurerm_prefix}-nsg-web-01` when instead it should be `${azurerm_network_security_group.Prod_nsg_Webservers.name}` to create the correct dependencies.

Comment: Yup, its working now. Just an issue with the NSG rules not working I'm sure i'll fix it. THanks again :)